# How to use new line in Python?

Tags: python

I'm using the following code:

```
for x in range(8):
  print(x,end=" ")   #Loop run for 8 times(from 0 to 7)

print('\n')

for x in range(1,8):
  print(x,end=" ")
```

When I run it, the output is:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

I only need one new line in the answer; that is, I want the output as:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve, I suggest that you reformat the question to improve readability

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for x in range(8):
    print(x, end=" ")

print()

for x in range(1,8):
    print(x, end=" ")
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.  Code-only answers are discouraged.

Answer (score 4):

The `print` function has a default end of a linefeed. If you tell it to print a linefeed, it will do that, and then add the default ending linefeed, resulting in two linefeeds. If you only want one, call it with no arguments:

```
print()
```

Answer (score -2):

Add another print statement between the loops:

```
print()
```

This will print the new line.

Comment: Adding another `print` call will simply print an additional unwanted blank line.